# How to change link previews (Open Graph) dynamically in a Client-Side Rendered React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-helmet, share-open-graph

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

const HotelHelmet = ({
  title,
  address,
  images,
  websiteSlug,
  city,
  state,
  descriptions,
  keywords,
}) => {
  return (
    <Helmet>
      <title>{title}</title>
      <meta name="description" content={descriptions} />
      <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
      <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta property="og:image" content={images[0]?.cdnImageUrl} />
      <meta property="og:description" content={descriptions} />
      <link rel="preload" as="image" href={images[0]?.cdnImageUrl} />
    </Helmet>
  );
};

export default HotelHelmet;
```

I'm getting all the data dynamically from DB but I'm not able to see the link preview with updated values while sharing the values in social media. Instead the default values set is being displayed but I want to display the updated values in the preview.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. Robots that scan graph tags don't run javascript

Comment: Have you considered server-side rendering?